# Toggle (On / Off) button as a slicer in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI report that describes sales data across multiple metrics

I want to add a toggle (On / Off) that can apply a filter to the data to show one sub-set of the data - a particular category of sales (A out of A,B and C).  The default position - Off - would show all sales, whereas on would only show sales under that category.

Is there a way of doing this as a check box / toggle without having to show all values of the category in a dropdown - i.e. I want to show either All Sales, or just those in category A and not give the user the option of explicitly choosing B and or C.

Comment: The Excel equivalent would be a Check Box from the Developer tab (or in Visual Basic / VBA, a check box).  The box would say "Show Category A only" and when checked, fire off a macro to filter to Category A only.  When deselected it would show all values.

Comment: You can use [Chiclet Slicer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/wa104380756?tab=overview).

Comment: Use bookmarks, to control what the uses sees. It saves a filter state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions guys.

I achieved the result I was looking for as follows:

- I added a normal slicer as a list (not a dropdown) and set the value in the new table as the field
- I applied a Filter to the slicer so that only the desired value (A) can be selected, and specifically no other values.

Now it operates like a check-box - you can either Select A or de-select it and no other options are available

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jon. [Bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-bookmarks) are a good way to do this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-bookmarks